# Как можно разделить 2 pickerview, чтоб не ругался xcode в swift 3?

Tags: xcode, swift

Вся проблема в функциях, где pickerview получает информацию о том, что ему отображать. А именно, что должна возвращать функция если return находится внутри if-else и xcode не видит и требует, что то вернуть.

```
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    if importanceTextField == importanceTextField {
    return importanceTextDataArray.count
    } else if typeTaskTextField == typeTaskTextField {
        return typeTaskArray.count
    }
    return "?"
}
```

Comment: а что это за return "?" в конце?

Comment: Ну это то, что туда надо что-то написать.

Comment: ну напишите return 0. делов то

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение получилось:

Создал второй pickerview (как оказалось использовал только 1 pickerview)

```
    typeTaskTextField.inputView = picker
    typeTaskTextField.delegate = self
    typeTaskTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar

    importanceTextField.inputView = picker2
    importanceTextField.delegate = self
    importanceTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
```

Добавил теги в viewDidLoad

```
    picker.tag = 1
    picker2.tag = 2
```

И стал проверять

```
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    if pickerView.tag == 1{
        return typeTask.count
    }
    if pickerView.tag == 2{
        return importanceTextData.count
    }
    return 2
}
```

И заработало))